# Multivariable calculus critical points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stationary-point

I've got the following equation for all $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $a$ is a real number:

$$f(x,y) = 4ay^2-x^2y^3-x^2$$

I want to calculate all critical points when:

- $a=0$
- $a>0$
- $a<0$

If I graph the various functions, I can see that with both $a<0$ and $a>0$, the function only has one critical point at the origin.

But if $a=0$ the function has critical points all along the y-axis.

Does anybody have any tips on how I can explain this in writing?

Comment: Ummm.... plug in the value of $a$ and take derivatives...

Comment: Yeah, but in the case of a=0 I get x=y=0, but when I graph the equation I can see that the critical points on y goes towards+/- infinity. I just don't know how to explain that. Could you help me? :)